# Angular & Bootstrap: data-toggle does not work with Angular

Tags: html, angular, navigation

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
  
  <div class="fixed-top">
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
      <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
        <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I don't know why, but the data-toggle simply does not work in my Angular codebase, although I have also installed and imported Bootstrap and JQuery in angular.json. The toggler icon simply does not show up. Do you guys have an idea how to check why it is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to run below command to into your angular application:

```
 npm install popper.js --save
```

after it also add popper.js file path into your angular.json script section

Therichpost

Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it still does not work, although I added jquery, popper.js and then the bootstrap, hence the order should be correct..